Does nested component slot usage prevent reactivity in quasar?
I have a simple image upload component using q-file to select files and use slots to preview the selected files within the q-file itself. Additionally I want to add a alt input within the qimage to store the alt along with the image. I am aware of q-uploader but I want to use q-file instead. But the preview does not work.
In order to focus on the preview part I have removed other parts:
<template>
  <q-file
    label="Select images"
    v-model="images"
    :accept="accept"
    @update:model-value="handleFileChange"
    clearable
    multiple
    append
  >
    <template v-slot:file="{ index, file }">
      <q-card class="q-pa-xs preview-card" :key="'preview_card_' + index">
        <q-img :src="getPreviewUrl(file.file)" :key="file.file.lastModified">
          <div>
            <q-input v-model="file.alt" placeholder="Enter Alt Text" />
          </div>
        </q-img>
        <!-- <q-input v-model="file.alt" /> -->
      </q-card>
    </template>
  </q-file>

  <q-btn @click="uploadImages" label="Upload" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const images = ref([]);
const props = defineProps({
  accept: {
    type: String,
    default: ".jpg,.jpeg",
  },
});

function handleFileChange(newFiles) {
  images.value = newFiles.map((file) => ({
    file,
    alt: "", // Initialize with empty alt text
  }));
}

function getPreviewUrl(image) {
  return URL.createObjectURL(image);
}
</script>

When I comment out the <!-- <q-input v-model="file.alt" /> --> then it works as expected displaying the preview, but without it the preview does not work. What could be the reason and solution for this?
Here is the codepen link (since it would be easier to fiddle here instead of on a paper :) ).

A question like this will have much better answers to be answered with a reproducible demo. This is not a problem that's easy to solve on paper

@EstusFlask ablsolutely, you are right.

This seems to be solely a layout problem, not related to reactivity. A card doesn't have its own width and q-input works as a spacer

@EstusFlask Yes, that was it! After adding the proper container to the q-card, it is now visible. The fact that it worked with the second input () initially misled me into thinking the issue was related to reactivity. I am still wondering why the second input made it work in the first place. Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Glad it helped. I didn't check thoroughly what happens in this flex layout the second q-input is a direct child of q-card, that's how it affects it
